# Cassandra 2.1.8: Node refuses to start with NPE in removeUnfinishedCompactionLeftovers

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a Cassandra 2.1.0 cluster to 2.1.8 (latest release).

When I start a first node with 2.1.8 runtime, I get an error and the node refuses to start.
This is the error's stack trace :

```
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.removeUnfinishedCompactionLeftovers(ColumnFamilyStore.java:642) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:302) [apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:524) [apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:613) [apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.removeUnfinishedCompactionLeftovers(ColumnFamilyStore.java:634) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
FSReadError in Failed to remove unfinished compaction leftovers (file: /home/nudgeca2/datas/data/main/segment-97b5ba00571011e49a928bffe429b6b5/main-segment-ka-15432-Statistics.db).  See log for details.
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.removeUnfinishedCompactionLeftovers(ColumnFamilyStore.java:642)
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:302)
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:524)
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:613)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.removeUnfinishedCompactionLeftovers(ColumnFamilyStore.java:634)
    ... 3 more
Exception encountered during startup: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The cluster has 7 nodes and it turns on AWS Linux EC2 instances.
The node I try to upgrade was stopped after a nodetool drain.
Then I tried to come back to 2.1.0 runtime but I now get a similar error.
I also tried to stop and start another node and everything was ok, the node restarted without any problem.

I tried to touch the missing file (as it should be removed, I thought it would perhaps not need a specific content). I had two other files with the same error that I also touched. And finally the node fails further while trying to read these files.

Anyone has any idea what I should do ?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth opening a Jira for that issue, so if nothing else, they can catch the NPE and provide a better error message.

It looks like it's trying to open:

file: /home/nudgeca2/datas/data/main/segment-97b5ba00571011e49a928bffe429b6b5/main-segment-ka-15432-Statistics.db

It's possible that it's trying to read that file because it finds the associated data file: (/home/nudgeca2/datas/data/main/segment-97b5ba00571011e49a928bffe429b6b5/main-segment-ka-15432-Data.db). Does that data file exist? I'd be tempted to move it out of the way, and see if it starts properly.

Comment: Thank you for advice. The node successfully started after removing every files prefixed with main-segment-ka-15432.
The problem might come from the way i copied data to my test cluster.
The upgrade probably doesn't have anything to see with the issue. But the strange thing is that the node first started without any problem.
So this issue still seems weird to me.